# What-if anything-is wrong with my raspberry?

Tags: raspberries

I am in zone 7. This is a heritage everbearing raspberry that is in its first year. It produces a crop in the fall and a crop in the spring, so they tell me. I have only had it a few months. I have noticed that the leaves now look kind of crinkly and have for the past week or so. I keep the soil moist. It has been mulched. I kind of "fluffed up" the mulch this morning. I do not know if this is fall dieback. It is about to produce raspberries. The soil is going to be tested this week (I'm new to this and the raspberry plant was a gift). It is in full sun for about 7 hours a day. I did hit it earlier in the season with a pesticide that was not supposed to hurt it but I am wondering about that now (fungicide 3). [![crinkly raspberry][1]][1]

I would appreciate any help-even if it's "just normal." I'm so new to this I don't know what I am doing!!! Thank you in advance!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGgp3.png[image]

Comment: Could you check the bottom part of the leaves and make an additional photo (on the leaves on the top, the bottom side). Maybe also a photo of the top site.  I think it could be some disease, but the colours could also indicate lack of some fertiliser.

Comment: It looks like the soil may be overly sweet. Any chance you could do a soil test?

Comment: The soil test is being done by the county extension service.

Comment: I don't know if I can get under it as that's going to put my phone right in the dirt but I will try. I do have another close up. Im having trouble adding more than one photo...sorry.

Comment: I forgot to mention I found out my mother sprayed the area before we planted it there...like, a few days...with roundup.

Comment: I did cut the malformed canes away and disposed of them in the garbage this morning. There is another primocane coming up and so far that one looks healthy. I still do not know what's wrong but as spindly as those were I felt like that was the best choice.

Comment: Roundup is quickly broken down when it is in contact with the soil but "a few days" in dry conditions may not have been long enough. Also you may have transferred some of it from the soil to the foliage with your hands, if you didn't know it was there. Either way, if it didn't actually kill the plant, the effects will only be temporary, as you seem to be finding with the new growth from the roots.